# How to fetch value of selected item in choice box from a table view coloumn in javafx

Tags: javafx

How can i fetch the value of the selected choice from the choce box in the following table.
column3 has 13 choice box nodes populated using following code.I want to fetch the selected item.

```
final ObservableList LogLevelList=FXCollections.observableArrayList("FATAL", "ERROR", "WARN", "INFO", "INOUT", "DEBUG");
column3.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Feature,String>,TableCell<Feature,String>>(){
@Override
public TableCell<Feature,String> call(TableColumn<Feature,String> param) { 
TableCell<Feature,String> cell = new TableCell<Feature,String>(){
@Override
public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
System.out.println("Inside UpdateItem");
ChoiceBox choice = new ChoiceBox(LogLevelList); 
choice.getSelectionModel().select(LogLevelList.indexOf(item));
//SETTING ALL THE GRAPHICS COMPONENT FOR CELL
setGraphic(choice);
}
}; 
return cell;
} 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Does the predefined ChoiceBoxTableCell do what you need?

```
column3.setCellFactory(ChoiceBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(logLevelList));
```

See if this helps:

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.ChoiceBoxTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableChoiceBoxTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final TableView<Feature> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setEditable(true);
        final TableColumn<Feature, String> nameCol = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        final TableColumn<Feature, String> logLevelCol = new TableColumn<>("Log level");
        logLevelCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("logLevel"));
        logLevelCol.setPrefWidth(150);

        final ObservableList<String> logLevelList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("FATAL", "ERROR", "WARN", "INFO", "INOUT", "DEBUG");
        logLevelCol.setCellFactory(ChoiceBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(logLevelList));

        table.getColumns().addAll(nameCol, logLevelCol);

        table.getItems().setAll(
            IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 20)
                .mapToObj(i -> new Feature("Item "+i, "FATAL")) 
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
            );

        Button showDataButton = new Button("Dump data");
        showDataButton.setOnAction(event -> table.getItems().forEach(System.out::println));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setCenter(table);
        root.setBottom(showDataButton);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static class Feature {
        private final StringProperty name ;
        private final StringProperty logLevel ;

        public Feature(String name, String logLevel) {
            this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name", name);
            this.logLevel = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "logLevel", logLevel);
        }

        public StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name ;
        }
        public final String getName() {
            return name.get();
        }
        public final void setName(String name) {
            this.name.set(name);
        }

        public StringProperty logLevelProperty() {
            return logLevel ;
        }
        public final String getLogLevel() {
            return logLevel.get();
        }
        public final void setLogLevel(String logLevel) {
            this.logLevel.set(logLevel);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return getName() + ": " + getLogLevel();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The provided ChoiceBoxTableCell updates the property of the associated item for you, so there's never any need to get the value from the ChoiceBox; you can just get the value from your model object.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are mistakes in your code. You do not want to display your Choice box in each and every cell of that column (i.e Emptied Row's Cell) and Also you should call super class function.

Now for getting the selected value of ChoiceBox , instead of just displaying your choicebox with the values you will have to save them in some ArrayList or Map or best options is to save inside your **Feature** class. So that you can finally use

```
@Override
public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item,empty);
    if(item != null){
        ChoiceBox choice = new ChoiceBox(LogLevelList); 
        choice.getSelectionModel().select(LogLevelList.indexOf(item));
        choice.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, String t, String t1) {
                 //either use   : myMap.put(getIndex(),t1); 
                 //or       : item.setChoice(t1);
            }
        });
        //SETTING ALL THE GRAPHICS COMPONENT FOR CELL
        setGraphic(choice);
    }
}
```

Also for demo of ChoiceBox in TableView there is one blog post for you :http://blog.ngopal.com.np/2011/10/01/tableview-cell-modifiy-in-javafx/

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response.I created and populated this table view using the link provided.And I want to add choice box to every row of that coloumn.I will try with the ChangeListener and let you know shortly.Thank you once again...!

Comment: You are welcome the blog post has the implementation of choicebox for Rating column as you can see